# Time complexity of algorithm involving function calls

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, big-o-notation

Me again.

This time I have a more general question.

Suppose I have the following code snippet:

```
int f(int k) {
  int s=0;
  for(int i=0; i<k*k; i++) {
   s++;
}
 return 2*k*k;
}
```

And the expression is:

`f(n) * f(f(f(n)));`

I am told that the complexity is `O(n^2) + O(n^2) + O(n^4) + O(n^8)`

I have several questions:

1. Why is there a plus sign when the function calls itself. Shouldn't it be "*" in between the last three terms?
2. What if the expression was `f(n) + f(f(f(n)));`, would it still be the same?

And lastly and most importantly,

3. What if it was this expression?

`f(n) + f(z)*f(f(n))`

This also confuses me very much. Most notably because there is a new variable `z`, and also because I am not sure that even if it was `f(n)` instead of `f(z)`, should I multiply the complexity with `f(f(n))` or add it to it.

Answer (score 0):

f(k) performs k^2 operations. f(n) returns 2n^2, f(f(n)) returns 8n^4, so you calculate f(n) * f(8n^4). This takes about 64n^8 operations and the result is 2n^2 * 128n^8 = 256 n^10.

There are O(n^4) other operations which we can ignore because that number is much smaller than 64n^8. The time complexity is O(n^8) or more precise $\theta(n^8)$.

However, any decent compiler will realise that all the additions are not needed and give the result in O(1).

In your second example, you calculate f(z) with z^2 operations, f(f(n)) with 4 n^4 operations, then multiply which is ONE operation. The product takes z^2 + 4m^4 + 1 operations.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following equivalent way of computing the expression:

```
x_1 = f(n);
x_2 = f(x_1);
x_3 = f(x_2);
return x_1 * x_3;
```

What are the (approximate) magnitudes of the different variables? What is the complexity of each call to `f`? What is the complexity of the multiplication on the last line? Then put this all together.

Comment: is this for my first or second expression?

Comment: @johndoe For your first expression. If you want it for your second expression, replace the multiplication with an addition.

Comment: The complexity of each call to function ```f``` is ```O(n^2)```, and the complexity of the last line is constant ```O(1)```.

How could I set up my second example in the same way? the

```f(n) + f(z)*f(f(n))```? This confuses me a bit since I have a function call that multiplies another function call (which calls the same function), to which you add another function call.

Comment: Are you sure the call `f(x_1)` happens in $O(n^2)$ time? It happens in $O(x\_1^2)$ time, but remember that `x_1` is $\Theta(n^2)$ already, so $O(x\_1^2)$ is actually $O(n^4)$. For the expression with `z` inside of it, it is impossible to get an asymptotic expression containing only `n` without knowing how big `z` is compared to `n`.

Comment: oh absolutely, sorry. I was saying that a function call has the time complexity of its squared argument. It would be different for ```f(f(n))``` in that it would be O(n^4).

Ah, okay I understand. What if instead of ```f(z)``` I had 

```f(n) + f(n)*f(f(n))```?